# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error on Angular-NodeJS app

Tags: nginx, node.js, deployment, angular-cli

I am trying to deploy my Angular-NodeJS app. I used nginx for Angular and PM2 for NodeJS. When I check the `localhost:3000` address on the server using a tunnel through SSH(This is the tunnel address that I built: `localhost:3030`), it shows the Express welcome message! But when I try to see the first page of the website I get these error messages:

```
main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/static/footer.jpeg net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
lookupStyle @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
willDisplay @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
updateWithValue @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
updateElement @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
setValue @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
setValue @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
ngOnChanges @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Fa.t.type.ngOnChanges.t.onChanges @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
En @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Dn @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Tn @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Sr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
xr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
template @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Hr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Yr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
co @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Yr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
co @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Yr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Fr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
po @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
detectChanges @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
tick @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
_loadComponent @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
bootstrap @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
_moduleDoBootstrap @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
onInvoke @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
run @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
onInvokeTask @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
runTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
m @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
Z @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
then @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
bootstrapModule @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
zUnb @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
l @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
0 @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
l @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
t @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
r @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Show 14 more frames
localhost:3000/images/static/Logo.jpeg:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/static/Logo.jpeg net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Image (async)
setProperty @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
setProperty @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
qr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
ra @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
ia @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
template @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Hr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Yr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
co @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Yr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Yr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
co @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Yr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Fr @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
po @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
detectChanges @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
tick @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
onInvoke @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
run @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
run @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
next @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
i @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
__tryOrUnsub @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
next @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
_next @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
next @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
next @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
emit @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Ul @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
onHasTask @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
hasTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
_updateTaskCount @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
_updateTaskCount @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
runTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
m @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
Z @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
then @ polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js:1
bootstrapModule @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
zUnb @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
l @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
0 @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
l @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
t @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
r @ runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.ed4c44a5d40d8e87ff1d.js:1
Show 12 more frames
localhost:3000/images/static/Home.jpeg:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/static/Home.jpeg net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I also can see the images in the address that it says there is no image(Like `http://localhost:3030/images/static/footer.jpeg`)!

When I check the `pm2 list` it also shows the NodeJS app and the MongoDB database are online:

```
│ 1  │ mongo              │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0.5%     │ 99.1mb   │
│ 2  │ www                │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0.4%     │ 57.1mb
```

I don't know why this happens and how can I fix it?